# Find an ith row and ith column such that all numbers in the row are zeros and all numbers in the column are ones

Tags: python, algorithm

The question asks to find an ith row and ith column such that the ith row only contains zeros, ane the ith column only contains ones (what is at their intersection doesn't matter) in linear time. If an i that satisfies this condition doesn't exist, just return -1. Here is the best I could come up with:

```
def zero_one(X):
    X = numpy.array(X)
    N = len(X)
    for i in range(N):
        original_value = X[i][i]
        X[i][i] = 0
        r = binaryToDecimal(X[i, :])
        X[i][i] = 1
        c = binaryToDecimal(X[:, i])
        if r == 0 and c == 2**(N - 1) - 1:
            X[i][i] = original_value
            return i
        X[i][i] = original_value
    return -1 # in case there's no i that satisfies the condition
```

Assuming that binaryToDecimal() runs in linear time and column-wise like in NumPy is available, this could be linear, but I doubt it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do an algorithm for this in O(n). It would be possible to have a lower bound of O(n) (roughly 2n, specifically), but the solution I'm thinking of would also have an upper bound of O(n^2).

Comment: Every element in the `i`th row must be checked, and every element in the `i`th column must be checked. Since `i` isn't already known, you must check every `i <= N`, which means `O(N^2)`. I don't think this can be done in `O(N)` either but algorithm analysis isn't my strong suit...

Comment: *"what is at their intersection doesn't matter"* Sadly, I think the problem would have been a lot easier if what was at their intersection did matter.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's doable in O(n) with a "tournament" strategy :
first we will eliminate all candidate but one, then we'll check if the last candidate is a valid answer.
I will give you a pseudo-code answer, because I don't know python, but it should be easy to implements.

1. make a variable "champion" containing the first index. (This variable will store the current winning index of the tournament).
2. For each other index j, match them against the champion index : if `X[champion][j]` is 0, then the champion stays, else champion becomes j
   (If `X[i][j]` is a 1, then the ith row contains a 1 and i is not valid, and if it's a 0 then the jth column contains a 0, and is valid. Each match will thus eliminate one possible candidate.)
3. Check if the champion satifies the conditions : if so return the champion, else return -1. (All other indexes have been eliminated during 2) )

EDIT : Tried to add python code.

```py
def zero_one(m):
    n = len(m)
    c = 0
    for j in range(1,n):
        if m[c][j] == 1:
            c = j
    for i in range(0,c-1):
        if m[c][i] == 1 or m[i][c] == 0:
            return -1
    for i in range(c+1,n):
        if m[c][i] == 1 or m[i][c] == 0:
            return -1
    return c
```

The complexity is 0(n) : you first check (n-1) element of the matrix during the tournament, and then check 2(n-1) element to validate the last index.

If you have any questions feel free to ask, I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I have a question though. What if there is more than 1 champion? What I mean is that there could be many m_ij values that are 0 but the rows they are in may not necessarily contain all zeros, but I need to make sure that if there is a champion, I find it

Comment: There can only be 0 or 1 champion : if we suppose that both i and j are champions, then what is the value of x[i][j] ? It should be both 0 (because i is a champion, so row i is all 0) and 1 (because j is a champion, so column j is all 1).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise there could be only 1 solution, but now that I tried to create a scenario with 2 champions, I noticed that if i happens to be a solution and the ith row contains all 0s, then all other columns will contain zeros, rendering them no longer suitable for the solution because none of them are at the intersection slots except for the intersection of the ith row and column. Is that what you meant?

Comment: exactly that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is simpler than it seems. Consider that if row `X` holds all zeros (apart for the intersection with column `X`) then no other column `Y!=X` can hold all ones.

Hence we only need to check the rows: if we find an all-zeros (but the intersection) row `X` then we check the column `X` and just return `X` or `-1` based on whether that column holds all ones (but the intersection). If no rows satisfy the criterion then we return `-1` as well.

So the worst case is, we have to check N rows and 1 column.

```
def zero_one(mx):
    n=len(mx)
    for x in range(n):
        if sum(mx[x])-mx[x][x] == 0:
            return x if sum(list(zip(*mx))[x])-mx[x][x] == n-1 else -1
    return -1
```

Comment: Checking N rows is still complexity O(n^2) though

Comment: @Alois Yes, it is; it is just a bit simpler and faster than the OP solution, since it checks n^2+n cells instead of 2*n^2. Your answer is definitely better thought of